# AEM wcm.io testing Sling MockProperty name encoding issue

Tags: aem, sling

I am experiencing an issue with the MockProperty implementation. My tests are currently failing because for some reason the ':' gets encoded to '%3A'. Why is this happening and how can I make this work?

NOTE: In my running code (outside of testing) this works all fine.

[image: properties]

[image: debug]

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource("path_to_a_valid_resource_here");
Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
PropertyIterator properties = node.getProperties();
while (properties.hasNext()){
    Property property = properties.nextProperty();
    String name = property.getName();
}
```

Comment: Please post an example of how you're creating the mocked property.

Comment: I get the mocked property from the PropertyIterator, see code above.

Answer (score 1):

The returned String is UTF-8 encoded. You can obtain the decoded value it by calling `String name = URLDecoder.decode(property.getName(), "UTF-8");`

Why this was encoded in the first place is unknown to me, but my guess would be that the property name is treated as a URL and subsequently encoded in the ASCII set, hence the transformation of `:` to `%3A`

Comment: Indeed, I also found this solution but still weird they are encoding it.